# Beamer - rounded corners around blocks and footnotes

Tags: beamer, footnotes, block

My aim is to get rounded corners without shadow ergo I used the following command
`\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=false]`

but it seems like that this option affects the footnotes as well, i.e. the footnotes behave like footnotes in a "column"-environment is this bug on my side and is there away to avoid this behavior and still get rounded corners around blocks?
[image]
[image]

Exempel.:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{boxes}
\usecolortheme{crane}
%\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=false] %<----!
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{This a title for the block}
This is the text inside block.\footnote{Footnotes are possible as well}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example `:)`

Answer (score 5):

The following gives want I think you wanted:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{boxes}
\usecolortheme{crane}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=false]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{Title}
This is a block\footnotemark
\end{block}
\footnotetext{My nice footnote}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: your example does work, could you explain to me why it's necessary to use `footnotemark` instead of the normal `footnote`-command -- is this a bug in beamer (esp. because it means that someone has to use the `footnotemark` through the complete presentation)?

Comment: @harry heller I cannot explain in detail. The trick I was using (replacing `\footnote` by `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`) is rather standard for footnotes in minipages or tables. What exactly happens in beamer I cannot fully explain.